# Reverse of Hausdorff Young Inequality

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, fourier-analysis, sobolev-spaces

The Hausdorff Young Inequality gives us that $$\|\hat f\|_{L^q(\mathbb{R}^n)} \leq \| f\|_{L^p(\mathbb{R}^n)}$$ if $1 \leq p \leq 2$ and $\frac{1}{q} + \frac{1}{p} = 1$, but does the converse also hold in general? Namely $$\|f\|_{L^q(\mathbb{R}^n)} \leq \| \hat f\|_{L^p(\mathbb{R}^n)}$$ for $1 \leq p \leq 2$ and $\frac{1}{q} + \frac{1}{p} = 1$? I am just confused on the dependence of the Fourier transform being less than the original function?

Comment: Hint. The Fourier transform of $\hat{f}$ is _almost_ $f$, so the answer is _yes_ - just apply the first statement.

Comment: As in, we can say $\|f\|_{L^q(\mathbb{R}^n)} \leq \| \hat f\|_{L^p(\mathbb{R}^n)} \leq C\| f\|_{L^q(\mathbb{R}^n)}$ for some constant C?

Comment: @DocStories: no, your last comment is incorrect. You wrote "the converse" in the question, but the displayed equation that follows is not the converse. Please check your $p$s and $q$s and make sure they are what you want. As _currently written_, the second inequality is true because the inverse Fourier transform and the Fourier transform just defers by taking the reflection $x\mapsto -x$. If you meant the version with $q$ and $p$ swapped, then the answer is no: there are even explicit counterexamples.